# How to tell TranslateMessage and DispatchMessage where WNDPROC Func is located at?

Tags: vb.net, api, user32

How to let Windows **TranslateMessage** and **DispatchMessage** know that it should trigger **WindowProcedure** Func, where i am awaiting the events!? I am trying to create a Native Form all based on Windows APIs. I have registered the class, created, showed, but i can't manage to hook the windows procedure function, remember i can't use  Forms.Form.WndProc(m as message) because the class isn't inheriting **Form**.

```
       'Run the message loop. It will run until GetMessage() returns 0 */
        While (GetMessage(messages, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0))
            '/* Translate virtual-key messages into character messages */
            TranslateMessage(messages)
            '/* Send message to WindowProcedure */
            DispatchMessage(messages)

            If (FORCECLOSE) Then PostMessage(hwnd, WindowsMessages.WmClose, 0, 0)
        End While



Function WindowProcedure(hwnd As IntPtr, message As UInt16, wParam As Integer, lParam As Integer) As Integer

  MsgBox("Event occurred!")
       Select Case message

       End Select
End Function
```

Comment: Please add a bit more context. All .Net GUI frameworks already take care of handling window messages. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Please view the edits.

Comment: I'm not sure that what you're trying to do is possible... There is a possibility that it won't recognize managed functions as `WindowProc` callbacks, but here are a few things you can try: **1)** I think you have to actually create a window before you can start processing messages, thus you'll need to call the `CreateWindow()` function. **2)** The `WindowProc` callback is called `WndProc` in native code, you can try calling yours that as well. **3)** The parameters of your callback are incorrect, they should be: `(hwnd As IntPtr, message As UInteger, wParam As IntPtr, lParam As IntPtr)`

Comment: Though I just noticed that the [**`WNDCLASSEX` structure**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633577(v=vs.85).aspx) has got a `lpfnWndProc` field that lets you specify a `WindowProc` callback. If you manage to P/Invoke that along with [**`RegisterClassEx()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633587(v=vs.85).aspx) and [**`CreateWindowEx()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632680(v=vs.85).aspx) you should have everything you need.

Comment: For information about the window's creation see: [**Creating a Window**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff381397(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Thank you Visual Vincent, i changed it but still same problem.

Comment: Yes Visual Vincent, you are right, i found before reading your comment that it was lpfnWndProc field in the WNDCLASSEX Structure that let me pass that delegate, for some reason i had uncommented that yesterday. Please see my edit, i impelemented it but still no luck.